# What is the suffix "-stretch" means in the circleci images?

Tags: java, circleci

https://github.com/CircleCI-Public/circleci-dockerfiles/tree/master/openjdk/images

I was looking at the list of available circleci managed images.  I noticed some jdk images end with suffix "-stretch".

#### Question

What does this suffix "-stretch" mean?  Is it somehow different from normal jdk (The ones without "-stretch")?

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/DebianStretch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suffix `stretch` in tags refer to the version of Debian that image is based on. In this case, Debian 9 "Stretch".